# How can I file fully qualified Domain name?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash

I am trying to get clean the file having domain names but they are not FQND (fully qualified domain names).
I have tried this script, but it is damn slow (For only 3 inputs taking more than 30 seconds):

```
for h in "bert" "ernie" "www.google.com"
do
    host $h 2>&1 > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "$h is a FQDN"
    else
        echo "$h is not a FQDN"
    fi
done
```

The input what I am trying to give is a big file containing the following:

```
example.com
examplecom.de
example1.com .com
Silverplate.ss.com
```

Where output should be only:

```
example.com
Silverplate.ss.com
```

Hope the idea is clear. Can it be done with some sed, awk, or other scripting used by Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: `examplecom.de` is an FQDN.

Comment: @muru No if you use the above bash script you will come to know that examplecom.de is not FQDN

Comment: I don't care what your bash script does, but `examplecom.de` fits the definition of an FQDN.

Comment: @muru But I do not want to have such domain. It is not valid. Don't you think the same?

Comment: What muru said. This script doesn't check if a string is an FQDN; it checks if the host succeeds a DNS lookup.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for explanation. Now I got what muru means..:)

Comment: Why is it invalid? Ok, technically an FQDN should have a trailing `.`, but for practical purposes, that's rarely specified. Otherwise `examplecom.de` has no problems whatsoever being an FQDN. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111881/what-are-the-allowed-characters-in-a-sub-domain

Comment: @JafferWilson on the error-some domains, are there any specifics? string, position of a specific string? In your example there is something to work with, but not sure if it is representative for your data.

Comment: @JacobVlijm All the data is placed line by line. and as you see that the pattern can be one single dot (.) ending with extension having only 2 characters. something like this. even there might be no dot in the line. what I am looking for is the the perfect domain name.

Comment: Then, why wouldn't examplecom.de be a perfect domain name? It could very well exist, I can register it now :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes you can. But currently, I need to process perfect domains. like example.com.de is a perfect domain for me. while exsmplecom.de is not.

Comment: It must be me, but what is the difference?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Actually trying to check the live domains and these type of input will slow my process. As I know it is not live at all.

Comment: The question is, I think, what is the quickest way to see if a domain exists?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52979/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-jacob-vlijm).

Comment: Hi Jaffer, need to run, but please do, I'll read it when I get back (late tonight probably)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sure.. :)